# Run code when user deletes module from a page

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I'm currently developing a DNN module. It would be nice if we were able to run custom code whenever a module is deleted from a page by the user, and also when a module gets restored from recycle bin.

I haven't found any examples on how this could be done, so I'm not sure if this is possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unaware of any event mechanism inside DNN where you could set your hooks. You could probably debug the DNN code and trace the call stack until you find a usable spot where you can inject some code (which would likely be destroyed after the next DNN update), or maybe detect a way that was intended to be used by the core team.

However, if a module is deleted from a page, the **IsDeleted field in the Modules table is set to true**. If it gets restored from the bin, it is again set to false.

You can use a **TRIGGER in your Sql Server** that fires when the Modules table is updated, checks if the update refers to an IsDeleted field, write stuff into a Notification table, and use Sql **Query Notification** based on SqlDependency to run some code (see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach for an introduction).

Some steps to go, but it should work (and be less exhausting than climbing the Matterhorn :-) ).

Comment: This is correct; there is no place in code where you can tie into this event.  The only semi-reliable place to take action would be via the trigger.

Comment: Great, thank you. Not as easy as I hoped it was, but I will definitely try to solve it with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely hooks in DNN Platform (DotNetNuke) that a developer can attached C# code to.

While there isn't a turn key example that I can provide at the moment, check out the following:

https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/c35fdc7fb75db0438f3b872ce4e279e3ea73e7c2/DNN%20Platform/Library/Entities/EventManager.cs

You are looking to hook onto the ModuleRemoved event by the sounds of it.

Here is an example for the user logging in that you could adapt to your event:

[Does DNN fire an event when a user logs in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646529/does-dnn-fire-an-event-when-a-user-logs-in)

I hope this helps in the future.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your answer to add some explanation and details. While it might answer the question, just adding some links does not help OP or future community members understand the issue or solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll look to add a concrete example here after creating a sample project.