# Does DNN fire an event when a user logs in?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I'm developing a module to automatically create a new user on a sister website when a current user logs into or registers a new account on our site. I already have the module working when a new account is registered. Now I need to find a way to trigger it when a user logs in. Any suggestions or guidance is most appreciated.

Comment: Are you using DNN registration & login modules OR any custom modules?

Comment: @Dexterity - I'm using DNN registration and login modules. BTW I'm running Evoq 8.

Comment: DNN doesn't have a good "Event" based model. You could monitor the Event log table, there is an event log record that can be stored when someone logs in, you might need to setup a process to monitor that and act upon it from there. Or use a custom registration/login module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNN 7.4 (Evoq 8.0) added event handling for users and sites.  So, you can create a class that implements `IUserEventHandlers` and annotate it with the `[Export(typeof(IUserEventHandlers))]` attribute, and DNN will automatically call your methods whenever a user is authenticated, as well as created, deleted, removed, and approved.

```
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Users;

[Export(typeof(IUserEventHandlers))]
public class MyUserEventHandlers : IUserEventHandlers
{
    public void UserAuthenticated(object sender, UserEventArgs args)
    {
        SisterSiteLibrary.CreateUserOnSisterSite(args.User);
    }

    public void UserCreated(object sender, UserEventArgs args)
    {
    }

    public void UserDeleted(object sender, UserEventArgs args)
    {
    }

    public void UserRemoved(object sender, UserEventArgs args)
    {
    }

    public void UserApproved(object sender, UserEventArgs args)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: A curiosity, do you know if there is an event when the User Logs out?  Or the login expires?  If you do - tell me and I will make a Question that you can Answer :)

Comment: @grantly - Did anyone ever answer you about an event firing when a user logs out?  I am also needing that functionality but haven't been able to find it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe No I didn't, but I think its possible - perhaps start a new Question - I would be interested :)

Comment: @bdukes Does this method also work on DNN 9? I have been trying it with no luck. I need to redirect to another page on successful login.

Comment: @HoudiniSutherland yes, this still works in DNN 9.  I know the login has its own redirect logic, so maybe it's overwriting your redirect.